# Differential geometry textbooks that define a smooth structure on $M$ as the set of all smooth real valued functions on open subsets of $M$

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, soft-question, definition, smooth-manifolds

I am looking for good textbooks on differential geometry that would consider the set of all differentiable/smooth functions $U\to\mathbf{R}$ for all open $U\subset M$ to be the main description of the differentiable/smooth structure on $M$ and would use it systematically. Any suggestions?

So far I've only found this one: Shlomo Sternberg, *Lectures on differential geometry* (1964).

The other textbooks I've seen so far define differentiable/smooth structures on $M$ using:

- coordinate systems or atlases on $M$ (Marcel Berger, Dubrovin -- Novikov -- Fomenko, Serge Lang, Michael Spivak, Frank Warner),
- local parametrizations of $M$ -- "inverted" coordinate systems (do Carmo -- Flaherty),
- embeddings or local embeddings of $M$ into $\mathbf{R}^n$ (John Milnor, James Munkres, Michael Spivak),
- pseudogroups of transformation on $M$ (Kobayashi -- Nomizu).

Comment: "Cohomology and differential forms" by Izu Vaisman.

Comment: @QuaereVerum, it does not look so, he talks about atlases.

Comment: "Manifolds, Sheaves, and Cohomology" by Torsten Wedhorn introduces Manifolds as locally ringed spaces (which is the description you ask about).

Comment: Of course he uses atlases, because the descriptions are equivalent. As is mentioned above, any treatment that approaches differential geometry from the viewpoint of locally ringed spaces adheres to your description, and the book I mentioned does this. Not to the exclusion of everything else, of course, because that is impractical.

Comment: In practice it is too inconvenient to do everything using only a single point of view in differential geometry. Almost anything you do can be done in at least three different ways and often there is one that is more illuminating and sometimes a different one with a simpler proof. The locally ringed approach is the one most rarely used.